# Query for Average Value based on distinct parameters

Tags: sql, ms-access

Data:

```
Project   Program    Month    Value

  1         aaa     1/1/20      25
  1         aaa     1/1/20      25
  2         aaa     1/1/20      25
  2         aaa     1/1/20      25
  1         bbb     1/1/20      25
  1         bbb     1/1/20      25
  1         bbb     1/2/20      25
  2         bbb     1/2/20      25
  2         bbb     1/2/20      25
```

Desired Output:

```
month   program   avg(based on the number of different projects)
1/1/20    aaa      100/2
1/1/20    bbb      50/1
1/2/20    bbb      75/2
```

I'm working in MS-Access to create a query which gets the Average of values based on the month and program.

And the Average is the total value from the same date divided by the count of distinct number of projects for that date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Access SQL you may need two subqueries:

```sql
SELECT 
    TableA.Month, 
    TableA.Program, 
    Sum(TableA.Value) As Total, 
    Projects, 
    Sum(TableA.Value)/Projects As Average
FROM 
    TableA
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT Month, Program, Count(*) As Projects
    FROM 
        (SELECT TableA.Month, TableA.Program, TableA.Project
        FROM TableA
        GROUP BY TableA.Month, TableA.Program, TableA.Project) As T2
    GROUP BY Month, Program) As T1
    ON T1.Month = TableA.Month And T1.Program = TableA.Program
GROUP BY TableA.Month, TableA.Program, Projects;
```

Result:

[image: Result]

Comment: Although it is a bit complicated, It does a great job. A little bit tweaking and I can use it for more than one outputs. 
Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use two levels of aggregation in MS Access:

```
select month, program, avg(value1)
from (select project, program, month, sum(value1) as value1
      from tableA
      group by project, program, month
     ) as a
group by month, program;
```

Comment: Initially it gave a circular reference caused by alias value so changed that. Then it couldn't recognize value. Asks me to enter parameter for value. It'll take a while for me to figure it out as I'm not profound in sql aggregations.

Comment: Oh figured it. Just changed the `avg(value)` to `avg(value1)` and `sum(value) as value` to `sum(value) as value1`.

Comment: Wish I could mark both as correct. Appreciate your time for helping me understand. Have a nice day.

Comment: @r00t . . . (1) In your question, the column is called `value` not `value1`.  (2) I think this is a much simpler solution than Gustav's, which is why I answered.

Comment: Yes it is value but if I type the exact code what you gave in access it gives a circular reference error. so in order for it to work i had to change it to
`select month, program, avg(value1)
from (select project, program, month, sum(value) as value1
      from tableA
      group by project, program, month
     ) as a
group by month, program;` **Note** that `sum(value)` hold the correct column "Value".
But then again I may very well be wrong. You clearly have more experience.  Forgive me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score -1):

I don't have access to MS-Access but i have tested below code on SQL server

```
SELECT cnt_project.Program,  cnt_project.Month,  sum_val.SM/cnt_project.CNT AS Average
from
(select Program , Month,  COUNT (distinct project) CNT  from TAB group  by  Program , Month) cnt_project
INNER JOIN 
 (select Program , Month,  SUM (VALUE) AS  SM  from TAB group  by  Program , Month) sum_val ON 
 cnt_project.Program = sum_val.Program AND 
 cnt_project.Month  = sum_val.Month
```

[Demo](https://rextester.com/RMYOLH66179)

Comment: I tried to replicate it in access and it threw a syntax error in the join statement. Apart form that `Count (distinct project)` won't work in access. So I'm still thinking how to fix it with `select count(project) from (select distinct(project) from tab);` and distinct works as a separate command can't add additional columns to it I think.